# datepickerIOS not coming on the screen

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a row where date is getting displayed on click of that view, I want a datepicker to pop up and display.

```
 class EditProfilePicture extends React.Component {
state = {
    currentDate: new Date()
};
setCurrentDateForIOS = currentDate => {
    this.setState({ currentDate });
};

pickDate = () => (
    <View>
        {Platform.OS === "ios" ? (
            <DatePickerForIOS
                setCurrentDateForIOS={this.setCurrentDateForIOS}
            />
        ) : (
            DatePickerForAndroid().then(currentDate =>
                this.props.changeBirthDate({ currentDate })
            )
        )}
    </View>
);
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.Container}>
                <Text style={styles.heading}>Your birthday</Text>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.pickDate}>
                    <View style={styles.dropdown}>
                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                            {DateFormatter(this.state.currentDate)}
                        </Text>
                        <Icon name="chevron-down" color={MED_GREY} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

And in DatePickerForIOS I have this---

```
 import React from "react";
 import PropTypes from "prop-types";
 import { DatePickerIOS } from "react-native";

 const DatePickerForIOS = props => {
   return (
    <DatePickerIOS
        date={new Date()}
        mode="date"
        onDateChange={() => props.setCurrentDateForIOS}
    />
);
};

DatePickerIOS.propTypes = {
 setCurrentDateForIOS: PropTypes.func.isRequired
 };

 export default DatePickerForIOS;
```

While the code works fine for android, in IOS the screen contains NAN/NAN/NAN as text initially and the datepicker doesn't open up when clicked on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DatePickerIOS` needs to be part of the render function of `EditProfilePicture`

Currently you create the component from`onPress` from `TouchableWithoutFeedback`.

You would need to do something like the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerios.html) say

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DatePickerIOS
          date={this.state.chosenDate}
          onDateChange={this.setDate}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

You would need to hide/show this a state boolean value to toggle on off. 
Without knowing your Android code, I suspect that is acting like a popup modal.

Another solution would be to use a package like [react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) which has the same interface between iOS and Android